# Printing a monthly calendar with custom pictures and events

Tags: open-source, calendar, printing

I want to print a monthly calendar on A3 (or 11x17", tabloid) paper, with spiral bindings in the middle of the (cut) sheet. The top half is a nice photo and the bottom is one month, with custom events that I control.

I know about [this LaTeX extension](https://github.com/profound-labs/wallcalendar) which produces full-page results with pictures, but it's hard to use, and [does not support full-page grids](https://github.com/profound-labs/wallcalendar/issues/4).

I also know about [this Inkscape plugin](https://goinkscape.com/create-a-custom-calendar-in-seconds/) but it only generates a full year on one page, not at all what I need. And there are various PDF, PowerPoint or ODT templates lying around, but none of those make my life any easier.

I want to programmatically generate the calendar. I have over 30 events I need to fill in and I don't want to do each by hand.

Said tool would also be free software based. Output would be PDF or SVG or some accessible format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the only practical way to do this "programmatically" is to use LaTeX. There are templates for various vector editing tools, but those all imply downloading a new template each year and it's unclear where the template comes from. Some you need to pay for.

I ended up going with the [wallcalendar](https://github.com/profound-labs/wallcalendar/) project. It's hard to use, but it gave me great results.

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance that you have an Apple Laptop / Desktop. You can print calendars from the calendars app, that comes installed, in many different ways, it's pretty flexible and has a lot of options.

Comment: Is that free software?

Comment: Yup, it's free (pre-installed) with any Apple Laptop / Desktop, it's not available for windows.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i meant "[free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)" as in "speech", not "beer".